# choose between different *.conf, based on current subnet

Tags: gentoo, subnet

I have gentoo running on a laptop that I use on two different networks. When I'm in the office there are a couple of tweaks I need/want in make.conf and resolve.conf.head: I have access to a local sync server and distributed compiling, and because of the way our dhcp is setup I need to add a line to resolve.conf.head to properly resolve intranet names. When I'm not on the office network I need to disable the resolve.conf.head and the distributed compile and local sync server in make.conf. Is there a way to make these changes automatically based on my current subnet? Perhaps by pointing a symlink to the appropriate *.conf file?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the extra lines you want to include for your office in separate files, e.g. `/etc/resolv.conf.office` and `/etc/make.conf.office`. Then in `/etc/make.conf`, you can write the following:

```
on_office_network && source /etc/make.conf.office
```

where `on_office_network` will be some command that runs successfully if and only if you are on your office network. If you can tell based on IP address, that command could be

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -q 'inet addr:192.168.1.1'
```

(where `192.168.1.1` should be replaced with whatever your IP address is on your office network).

Since `/etc/resolv.conf` is not a bash script, you'll need to use a different technique there. The first thing I would ask is why the extra line you need isn't automatically inserted by DHCP, and whether there's some way you could modify `/etc/conf.d/net` to make it show up.  If not, then I guess making `/etc/resolv.conf.head` a symlink and altering it to point to `/etc/resolv.conf.office` whenever you connect to the office network is probably a good way to go. Unfortunately, I don't know how to trigger a process to run whenever you connect to (or disconnect from) a network.

If you don't wind up getting good answers here, you might want to ask on the [Gentoo Forums](http://forums.gentoo.org/).